# Dynamically provide argument to function inside mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, lazyeval

First off - my apologies if this has been asked before, I've looked and haven't been able to find anything that matches what I'm trying to do.

I'm trying to create a function that bins data according to a user-generated column in a data frame. To do this, I'm using the mutate() function from dplyr and cut() from base R. However, I can't figure out how to use a column name that's passed through a function inside the cut() function (which appears inside mutate).

I've spent several hours looking through [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lazyeval/vignettes/lazyeval.html#fnref1) and [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html) but still haven't figured it out. My understanding is that foo(), bar() and the final line in the code below should all produce the same output. However, I get two errors for the functions, and the one that isn't wrapped in a function and just uses a hard coded column name works fine.

What's going on here? Why does foo() produce a different output than bar()? And how do I correctly use lazyeval to allow the correct behavior in a function?

```
library(dplyr)
library(lazyeval)

foo <- function(data, col, bins){
    by = lazyeval::interp(quote(x), x = as.name(col))
    print(paste0("typeof(by): ", typeof(by)))
    print(paste0(" by: ", by))

    df <- data %>%
      dplyr::mutate(bins = cut(by,
        breaks = bins,
        dig.lab = 5,
        include.lowest = T))
    df
}

bar <- function(data, col, bins){
  df <- data %>%
    dplyr::mutate(bins = cut(lazyeval::interp(quote(x), x = as.name(col)),
      breaks = bins,
      dig.lab = 5,
      include.lowest = T))
  df
}

#produce sample data and bins list
df <- expand.grid(temp=0:8,precip=seq(0.7,1.3,by=0.1))
df$rel <- seq(40,100,length=63)
bins <- seq(40,100,by=10)

foo(df,"rel",bins) # produces "Error: 'rel' not found"
bar(df,"rel",bins) # produces "Error: 'x' must be numeric"

# but this works
dplyr::mutate(df, bins = cut(rel, breaks = bins, dig.lab = 5, include.lowest = T))
```

Comment: I would probably have something like `mutate_(bins = interp(~cut(x, bins, dig.lab = 5, include.lower = TRUE), x = as.name(col)))` in the function.

Comment: @aosmith Thinking through this more, I'm struggling to understand why it works. It seems like interp() is executing before cut, but all of my previous coding experience teaches me that functions execute from the inside out.

Comment: To understand more of the details it might help you to read the [non-standard evaluation section](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) of Advanced R.  You first link covers some of the same info.  I think the sections on capturing expressions to be evaluated later may be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @aosmith mentioned in their comment, the solution is to use `mutate_(bins = interp(~cut(x, bins, dig.lab = 5, include.lowest = TRUE), x = as.name(col)))`. Using `mutate_` instead of `mutate` allows us to use standard evaluation.

It's easiest to see what's going on with `interp` and `cut` if we call `interp` outside of `mutate_`. (It executes the same either way.) Assuming `col == "rel"`,

```
call = interp(~cut(x, bins, dig.lab = 5, include.lowest = TRUE), x = as.name(col)))
```

will give

```
~cut(rel, bins, dig.lab = 5, include.lowest = TRUE)
```

Inserting this expression into mutate allows us to exactly follow the examples provided [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html).

```
muatate_(bins = call)
```

Gives the correct result.

You could also allow the user to provide a column name that replaces "bins":

```
dplyr::mutate_(.dots = setNames(call, c(binName)))
```